# Is there a correlation between a semi-transparent color and a semi-transparent overlay?

Tags: html, css, colors

Is there any correlation between:

1. Placing a semi-transparent content over a solid color background;
2. Placing a semi-transparent overlay over a solid color content.

HTML:

```
<p><span>Lorem</span></p>
```

CSS 1:

```
p {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
span {
    color: black;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

CSS 2:

```
p:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    opaity: .5;
    z-index: 999;
}
span {
    color: black;
}
```

I can't always tell the difference visually, so I thought maybe there is some kind of a ratio for that, or are those totally different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the opacity is `0.5` for both - there's no difference.

Logically if black text is at 0.3 opacity, to get the same effect using a white overlay, the overlay needs 0.7 opacity over an opaque black text.

```js
var text    = document.getElementById("a");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

document.getElementById("opacity").addEventListener("input", function() {
  text.style.opacity    = this.value;
  overlay.style.opacity = 1-this.value;
  console.clear(); console.log( this.value );
});
```

```css
#test{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
#a{
  
}
#b{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%; height:100%;
  top:0; left:0; 
}
#overlay{
  background:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; left:0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="opacity" type="range" val=1 step=0.1 min=0 max=1>

<div id="test">
  <div id="a">LOREM</div>
  <div id="b">LOREM <div id="overlay"></div></div>
</div>
```

the above controls both opacities, but the exact same can be achieved controlling text color like `rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)` and the overlay's background color like `rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)`

Comment: What if I use a text of .3 opacity, should the overlay be of .7 opacity to make it look the same?

Comment: @sdvnksv math. Yes. if text at 0.3 over a white background is light gray - - - means that black text needs 70% lightness (white overlay at 0.7) to make it look the same light gray.

Comment: @sdvnksv created a demo using overlapping elements.

Comment: nice one! Thanks!